# Analytical solution of equation involving the CDF of the normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

I have an r.v. $\sim \text N(65, 38)$ and I need to add a constant c to the r.v. so the probability of the new r.v. being between 70 and 80 is 0.5. I end up having to solve this equation:

$$ Φ\left( \frac{15-c}{\sqrt{38}} \right) - Φ\left( \frac{5-c}{\sqrt{38}} \right) = \frac12$$

Is it possible to analytically solve this for c or do i have to try different values of c?

Comment: What have you tried to do?

Comment: Until now nothing I don't know how to proceed from here. I know i can plot the left part of the equation for different values of c and see what c gives me 0.5, though I want to know if it is possible to analytically find c first.

Comment: Totally revised

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{2} \text{erf}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
the equation to solve is
$$\text{erf}\left(\frac{15-c}{2 \sqrt{19}}\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{5-c}{2 \sqrt{19}}\right)-1=0$$

Let
$$\frac{10-c}{2 \sqrt{19}}=t \qquad \text{and}\qquad k=\frac{5}{2 \sqrt{19}}$$ and look for the zeros of function
$$f(t)=\text{erf}\left(k+t\right)+\text{erf}\left(k-t\right)-1$$

Expanding as a series arount $t=0$
$$f(t)=(2 \text{erf}(k)-1)-\frac{4 e^{-k^2} k}{\sqrt{\pi }}t^2-\frac{2 e^{-k^2} k \left(2 k^2-3\right)}{3 \sqrt{\pi }}t^4+O(t^6)$$

Using the expansion to $O(t^4)$ gives as an estimate
$$t=\pm \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\pi } e^{k^2} (2 \text{erf}(k)-1)}{4 k} }=\pm 0.421369$$ that is to say

$$\color{blue}{c_1=6.3266}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \color{blue}{c_2=13.6734}$$

while the exact values are $\color{red}{c_1=6.1885}$ and $\color{red}{c_2=13.8115}$

Solving the quartic equation in $t^2$ gives $t=\pm 0.438100$  that is to say

$$\color{green}{c_1=6.1807}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \color{green}{c_2=13.8193}$$

**Edit** (*just for your curiosity*)

We can do better and simpler building the simplest Padé approximant
$$\text{erf}\left(k+t\right)+\text{erf}\left(k-t\right)=\frac{2 \text{erf}(k)+\left(\left(1-\frac{2 k^2}{3}\right) \text{erf}(k)-\frac{4 e^{-k^2}
   k}{\sqrt{\pi }}\right)t^2 } {1+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{k^2}{3}\right) t^2 }+O(t^6)$$ from which
$$t=\pm \frac 1 {\sqrt{\frac{4 e^{-k^2} k}{\sqrt{\pi } (1-2
   \text{erfc}(k))}+\frac{k^2}{3}-\frac{1}{2} }}$$ which gives $t=\pm 0.436777$ and then
$$\color{purple}{c_1=6.1923}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \color{purple}{c_2=13.8077}$$

Comment: I plotted the left part of the equation for different values of c here:
https://imgur.com/a/aMIEtnD
One solution is near 6 like you approximated, however there is one more solution near 14. How would i approximate the second solution?